# Python regular expression not matching end of line

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a C/C++ function definition using a fairly complex regular expression.  I've found a case where it's not working and I'm trying to understand why.  Here is the input string which does not match:

```
   void Dump(const char * itemName, ofstream & os)
```

which clearly is a valid C++ method declaration.  Here is the RE:

```
   ^[^=+-|#]*?([\w<>]+\s+(?!if|for|switch|while|catch|return)\w+)\s*\([^;=+-|]*$
```

This basically tries to distinguish between other C syntax which looks like a method declaration, i.e. which has words followed by paraentheses.

Using the very useful Python regular expression debugger (http://www.pythonregex.com/) I've narrowed it down to the trailing "$" - if I remove the trailing $ in the regular expression, it matches the method signature above; if I leave in the $, it doesn't.  There must be some idiosyncracy of Python RE's that is eluding me here.  Thanks.

Comment: You really need a proper parser to do this kind of thing properly.

Comment: A quick search suggests you might use http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - this is part of Code Surveyor, a quick and dirty tool to do some analysis of a code base.  I know a real parser working on ASTs would be much more accurate - I actually have that in Visual Studio, but the downside of many parsers is that the code has to actually compile.  This allows it to run on codebases that have issues with building.  I'll look at the reference you provided, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `+-|` in your character class `[^;=+-|]` is a *range* specification. This will result in the character class containing (actually excluding since you're using `^`) much more than you intend. To specify a literal `-` in a character class, mention it first like `[^-;=+|]`.

Answer (score 1):

The output of [PythonRegex](http://www.pythonregex.com/) is somewhat misleading.  The results of `r.groups()` and `r.findall()` are both the same: `u'void Dump'`, which is the content of the first capturing group.  If it showed the whole match, you'd see that when remove the `$` you're only matching

```
void Dump(
```

...not the whole function definition as you intended.  The reason for that (as Greg explained) is a syntax error in your last character class.  You need to escape the hyphen by listing it first (`[^-;=+|]`) or last (`[^;=+|-]`), or by adding a backslash (`[^;=+\-|]`).

The only way I can see to get PythonRegex to show the whole match is by removing all capturing groups (or converting them to non-capturing).